# prevent drag event after pinch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

How can I prevent the `$ionicGesture` event 'drag' after 'pinchin' or 'pinchout'?

I have tried `e.preventDefault()`, `e.gesture.preventDefault()`, but the drag event still be triggered.

```
$ionicGesture.on("drag", function (e) {
    cursor_gesture = e.gesture;
    cursor_center = cursor_gesture.center;
    _drag_to_edit();
}, photo);
$ionicGesture.on("pinchin", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    e.preventDefault();
}, photo);
$ionicGesture.on("pinchout", function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    .preventDefault();
}, photo);
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also try these:

```
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.gesture.stopPropagation();
    event.gesture.preventDefault();
    event.gesture.stopDetect();
```

Comment: I think preventDefault will only prevent the default browser action to be run along with the event handler. And stopPropagation will only stop the event bubbling so IMHO they are not relevant to other types of events.

Answer (score 0):

Manually block other events handlers for a given amount of time :

```
var lastPinchTime = undefined;
var dragBlockTimeAmmount = 1000; //1 second
$ionicGesture.on("drag", function (e) {
  if( (new Date() - lastPinchTime) < dragBlockTimeAmmount){
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  else {
   // ...
   // your code here
   // ...
  }

}, photo);
$ionicGesture.on("pinchin", function (e) {
    lastPinchTime = new Date();
}, photo);
$ionicGesture.on("pinchout", function (e) {
    lastPinchTime = new Date();
}, photo);
```